How to measure query processing time in an Apache Flink stream?
I am using Apache Flink for streaming data processing where I need to measure the processing time for specific query operations on a stream. Here is how I am currently attempting to measure it:
DataStream<MyDataObject> myDataStream = ...; // source data stream

// Set the processing start time for each data object
myDataStream = myDataStream
    .map(new MapFunction<MyDataObject, MyDataObject>() {
        @Override
        public MyDataObject map(MyDataObject obj) throws Exception {
            obj.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return obj;
        }
    }).startNewChain();

// Assign timestamps and watermarks to the stream
DataStream<MyDataObject> timestampedStream = myDataStream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy.<MyDataObject>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(0))
            .withTimestampAssigner((element, recordTimestamp) -> element.getTimestamp())
    );

// Apply a window function to perform calculations
DataStream<MyResultType> resultStream = timestampedStream
    .keyBy(MyDataObject::getKey)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
    .apply(new WindowFunction<MyDataObject, MyResultType, Integer, TimeWindow>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(Integer key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<MyDataObject> input, Collector<MyResultType> out) {
            MyDataObject firstElement = null;             
            if (elements.iterator().hasNext()) {                 
               firstElement = elements.iterator().next();
            }
            long startTime = firstElement.getStartTime();
            MyResultType result = computeResult(input);  // Placeholder for computation method
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Query processing time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
            out.collect(result);
        }
    });




In this setup, I am unsure if this is the optimal way to measure the time taken for query processing within Flink. Are there more efficient or standardized methods to achieve precise timing for query operations in a Flink stream?
DataStream<MyResultType> resultStream = timestampedStream
    .keyBy(MyDataObject::getKey)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
    .apply(new WindowFunction<MyDataObject, MyResultType, Integer, TimeWindow>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(Integer key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<MyDataObject> input, Collector<MyResultType> out) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            MyResultType result = computeResult(input);  // Placeholder for computation method
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Window processing time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
            out.collect(result);
        }
    });

Another method I tried involves calculating processing time within the window. However, it appears that this measurement only starts when the window is triggered.
If the system's load exceeds its capacity, causing backpressure, the processing time still seems minimal. It seems only tied to the volume of data per key in the current window, rather than the overall system load.
Conversely, if I set the start time before the keyBy operation , this processing time would include the time windows spend waiting for data.
During stress testing, I observed that when the subtask was 90% busy, the processing time was not much different from when it was 10% busy.
However, once it reaches 100% capacity, backpressure occurs.Data accumulates in the input buffer at the keyBy stage, which means the start timestamp is set early, but computation is delayed until much later. This scenario results in processing times that are significantly longer than under normal conditions, which does not seem reasonable.
Considering these observations, how should I accurately calculate data processing time under such conditions?
